# How to Download to Computer a Voice Memo Received via MMS on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, audio

A friend sent me a Voice Memo recorded on their iPhone, to mine through MMS. How might I go about getting this audio from my phone to my computer?

I've already tried syncing Voice Memos through iTunes, but apparently that's only used for memos recorded on the actual iPhone in question. Since this was recorded on another, it did nothing.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Forward the MMS to your E-Mail.

The Email client of your computer can then extract the attachment.

1. In the SMS/MMS view, touch **edit** in the upper right-hand corner.
2. Touch the circle to the left of the audio clip(s) you want to keep or send to others.
3. Touch **forward** at the bottom and then type in the email address that is linked to your phone, or touch the **+** and you can pick any of your contacts and send it to their cell/email.